# Stress test with different user agents

Tags: stress-testing

I am trying to do stress test on a webpage with different user agents,

I am trying siege, but it looks like only supports only one user agent for a particular test, 
How do i randomize user agents for each request in a particular test.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you committed to using Siege?  May want to indicate that in the title if so.

Answer (score 1):

With [Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html), you can put as many user agents as you want into a list and substitute that into the User-Agent header. Once the list has been created, it takes about 1 minute to make the configuration change.